# retrieve scheduled posts in reverse order with facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I have an app that posts a scheduled post to a page 3 hours after the last post.

the problem is that there doesn't seem to be a quick way (that I've found) that can retrieve all scheduled posts in descending order so the post with the latest date is first in the list

is there a fql query or another way that I can bring back all scheduled posts in reverse order so I can grab the scheduled_publish_time from the first array key easily?

the code I'm using is

```
$posts = $facebook->api($fanpage.'/promotable_posts?limit=500');
$scheduledposts = array();
if($posts){
// find last published post
$time = time();
foreach($posts['data'] as $post){
    if($post['is_published'] == false){
        $scheduledposts[] = $post;
        if($time < $post['scheduled_publish_time']){
            $time = $post['scheduled_publish_time'];  
        }
    }
}
$timetopost = $time + 10800;                                        
}
// sort scheduled posts by order of scheduled_publish_time in reverse
usort($scheduledposts, function($a, $b) {
 return $b['scheduled_publish_time'] - $a['scheduled_publish_time'];
});
```

the order of the $posts array isn't always chronological and what if there are more than 500 posts in the schedule? I want to be able to retrieve just the last 5 scheduled posts that have the scheduled_publish_date furthest away

Comment: In your loop, you could just append the next element to the beginning of the array each time instead of adding it at the end … `array_unshift`

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to have to retrieve 500 posts if I have 500 posts scheduled. I want to retrieve just the last 5 posts

Comment: I was able to add a query arg to the url and it was able to return the last 5 unpublished posts with `$posts = $facebook->api($c['active']['id'].'/promotable_posts?limit=5&is_published=0');`